# Array to string conversion in php _construct()

Tags: php

I have a PHP class with a __construct() method. I pass parameters and store them in properties.  Like this:

```
class BlogList {

  private $app_config, $texts;

  public function __construct($app_config, $texts) {
      $this->$app_config = $app_config;
      $this->$texts = $texts;
  }

  ...

}
```

When I create an instance of this class I see that the logs say this:

```
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /path/to/blogList.php on line 6
```

I get this for both assignments in the __construct method. Both $app_config and $texts are arrays

Why is this conversion done? And how can I prevent it?

Comment: Don't use variable variables when you assign the properties in the construct.  $this->app_config

Comment: I read over that like 1000 times. I am a n00b.  Thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The assignments should be:

```
public function __construct($app_config, $texts) {
    $this->app_config = $app_config;
    $this->texts = $texts;
}
```